# Salesforce Apex System.runAs not reflected in trigger context

Tags: triggers, salesforce, profile, apex, dml

I have a test class, with this code

```
System.debug(UserInfo.getProfileId());

Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'];
User u = new User(ProfileId = p.Id, ...);
System.runAs(u)
{
    System.debug(UserInfo.getProfileId());

    Database.delete(records, false);
}
```

In the trigger handler that fires for this DML operation, when I output the current user`s Id

```
System.debug(UserInfo.getProfileId());
```

It does not get the Profile Id of the User that I set in the `System.runAs` method. It gets the Profile Id of the User... me, ie. the System Administrator, when it should be the Standard User.

Why?... And how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The Trigger execution is at System Context level. Place your login in Apex Class (with sharing) for User Context.